# How can you get the innerHTML of an object you've just passed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game so that whenever a person clicks a button, it will also create an object in the gameBoard array, but I want that from apart of printing it into the `gameBoard` array I want it to also output it in the innerHTML. I've tried adding an innerHTML next to `[e.target.id]` but this doesn't seem to work.

I guess it is a quick fix but wasn't able to find the answer. What would be a method to do it?

```
  const game = (() => {
      const createPlayer = (name, marker, turn) => {
        return {name, marker, turn}
      }
    
      player1 = createPlayer('Player 1', "x", true)
      player2 = createPlayer('Player 2', "o", false)
    
      const gameBoard = () => {
        var gameBoard = []
    
    
        const movement = (e) => {
          if (player1.turn === true){
//trying to convert this into innerHTML so that whenever the person clicks a button, it also gets printed in the innerHTML
            gameBoard[e.target.id] = player1.marker
            player1.turn = false
          } else if (player1.turn === false) {
            gameBoard[e.target.id] = player2.marker
            player1.turn = true
          }
        }
    
    
    
        document.querySelector('.item-board').addEventListener('click', movement)
    
        console.log(gameBoard)
    
      }
      gameBoard()
    })
    
    game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `innerHTML` property on event.target so you can do something like this:

```
e.target.innerHTML = player1.turn ? player1.marker : player2.marker;
```

Answer (score 0):

**using Vanila JS**

```
const content = element.innerHTML;
```

**Using jquery**

setting inner html of a tag

```
$("p").html("Hello <b>world</b>!");
```

getting innerhtml of a tag

```
$("p").html();
```